# what are all finite subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}^n \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$\mathbb{Z}^n \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_2$ := $\{(u_1,u_2....,u_n,t), u_iu_j=u_ju_i, tu_jt=u_j^{-1},t^2=1\}
$

1. what are all finite subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}^n \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_2$? (in terms of the generators $u_1,u_2....,u_n,t$)
2. what are all finite maximal subgroups up to conjugacy for the same $\mathbb{Z}^n \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_2$? (in terms of the generators $u_1,u_2....,u_n,t$)

Comment: You haven't defined it properly. Is this $1$ maps to the negation action and $0$ to the identity?

Comment: $0$ has to go to the identity, so yes, of course he he saying $1$ goes to $x\to -x$. @JohnFernley

Comment: of course $\mathbb{Z}^n$ means direct sum of $n$ copy of $\mathbb{Z}$. And the action of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is $(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ goes to $(-x_1,-x_2,...,-x_n)$.

Comment: I'm not even sure I know what the subgroups of $\mathbb Z^n$ are :)

Comment: ohh sorry i mean finite subgroups.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't have that many finite subgroups: $(\Bbb Z_2)^n\rtimes \Bbb Z_2$ is the only maximal finite subgroups.

Comment: @QuangHoang, how is $\Bbb Z_2$ a subgroup of $\Bbb Z$?

Comment: @blue: I wasn't thinking apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to check that the nontrivial elements in $\Bbb Z^n$ have infinite order, any element outside of it has order two, and any two elements outside of it multiply to get a nontrivial element of $\Bbb Z^n$.

Therefore, the only finite subgroups are of the form $\langle g\rangle=\{e,g\}$ with $g$ not in $\Bbb Z^n$.

Explicitly, given your presentation of $\Bbb Z^n\rtimes C_2$, every element can be written in the standard form as $u_1^{e_1}\cdots u_n^{e_n}t^\epsilon$ with $e_1,\cdots,e_n\in\Bbb Z$ and $\epsilon\in\{0,1\}$. The $g$s mentioned are those with $\epsilon=1$.

Since all nontrivial finite subgroups have order $2$, they are all maximal among finite subgroups, but when are they conjugate? Note $\langle g\rangle\sim\langle h\rangle$ iff $g\sim h$ in this case, so we can instead ask when two elements in standard form are conjugate. For convenience, we can write elements as $u$ and $ut$, where $u\in\Bbb Z^n$ is a vector. Then $x(ut)x^{-1}=xuxt$ and $(xt)ut(xt)^{-1}=xtuttx^{-1}=xu^{-1}xt$. Thus the conjugates of $ut$ are $vt$ with $v$ in the same coset of $2\Bbb Z^n$ as $u$. Therefore, the subgroups

$$\{{\rm identity},u_1^{\epsilon_1}\cdots u_n^{\epsilon_n}t\}$$

for $\epsilon_1,\cdots,\epsilon_n\in\{0,1\}$ chosen independently are pairwise nonconjugate and every finite subgroup is conjugate to one of them. This is the full classification for question 2.

Comment: can I get the answer in terms of generators? the question is little bit edited (more clarified) just now.

Comment: @jeevan Do you follow my reasoning? Were you able to check the things I said to check? Are you unable to figure out how to write the elements not in $\Bbb Z^n$ using your presentation? Every element is of the group is form $u_1^{e_1}\cdots u_n^{e_n}t^\epsilon$ with $e_1,\cdots,e_n\in\Bbb Z$ and $\epsilon\in\{0,1\}$, so what would be the "elements not in $\Bbb Z^n$"?

Comment: yes, thanks. what about the 2nd question?

Comment: for $\mathbb{Z}^2$ I guess the generator elements are $t,u_1t, u_2t, u_1u_2t$

Comment: What do you mean by "the generator elements"?

Comment: the subgroups generated by those single elements.

Comment: @jeevan Correct.